# Detect availability of Linux kernel's AF_ALG sockets for userland crypto?

Tags: c, sockets, linux-kernel, cryptoapi

The Linux kernel added a user space API to its crypto functions at 2.6 via a new new socket family *`AF_ALG`*. Also see [crypto: af_alg - User-space interface for Crypto API](http://lwn.net/Articles/410536/) on LWN.

I'm working with Gentoo, and it requires one to configure and build the kernel. It appears the default settings omit *`AF_ALG`*, so I'm [currently] working with a kernel that lacks the support. OpenSSL 1.1.0 has an Engine interface into the crypto API. Its failing its self tests due to lack of support for *`AF_ALG`*.

I'd like to know how to detect availability of *`AF_ALG`* at both compile time and runtime. I have not found a way to detect availability at compile time. I think we can use *`alg_get_type`* to detect runtime availability, but I'm not certain.

How can I determine availability of *`AF_ALG`* at compile time and at runtime?

---

The [`socket(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) man pages has this to say: *"Some socket types may not be implemented by all protocol families."* But it does not discuss how to detect availability.

The kernel docs cover the API in [Chapter 4. User Space Interface](http://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/crypto-API/User.html), but it does not appear to discuss how to detect availability.

---

For completeness, it looks like the following kernel configuration parameters need to be set for Gentoo (from Marek Vašut's [Utilizing the crypto accelerators](https://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/lcj-2014-crypto-user.pdf)):

- `CONFIG_CRYPTO_USER_API=m`
- `CONFIG_CRYPTO_USER_API_HASH=m`
- `CONFIG_CRYPTO_USER_API_SKCIPHER=m`

Comment: On a side note, I wonder who decided it was sensible to make the main entry point to their new crypto API be an *address family*.

Comment: @immibis - I'm just guessing, but I think it had something to do with asynchronous I/O, `syscall`, `__NR_io_setup`, `__NR_eventfd` and `__NR_io_destroy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the only way to detect at compile time is to write a separate program that will do a runtime check for AF_ALG sockets and create a header file with a define such as `#define AF_ALG_AVAILABLE`.

Expanding on your answer to the second question, you may want to make sure errno holds `EAFNOSUPPORT`. Otherwise, another error, such as being out of file descriptors, will make your program falsely believe that AF_ALG is not supported, which could be bad if you are checking for AF_ALG at compile time using my method.

Checking at compile time:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <linux/if_alg.h>

int main(){
    //Alternatively you can set the path to argv[1]
    FILE *f = fopen("/path/to/output/file", "w");
    if(f == NULL){
        //Handle error
    }
    int sockfd = socket(AF_ALG, SOCK_SEQPACKET, 0);
    if(sockfd == -1){
        if(errno == EAFNOSUPPORT){
            //Unavailable, put whatever you want here
            fprintf(f, "#define AF_ALG_UNAVAILABLE\n");
        } else {
            //Unable to detect for some other error
        }
    } else { //AF_ALG is available
        fprintf(f, "#define AF_ALG_AVAILABLE\n");
    }
    close(sockfd);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Then just compile and run that in your makefile, and you will find your header file where you put it. Then you can simply select what code to use using `#ifdef AF_ALG_AVAILABLE`.

Comment: Note that you can’t perform this check at compile-time if you want to support cross-compilation. Your program should check at runtime instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think I can answer some of the second question, runtime availability, with the following:

```
int ret = socket(AF_ALG, SOCK_SEQPACKET, 0);
if (ret != -1)
  close(ret);

int supported = ret != -1;
```